# PWM Low Pass Filter - struggling to get required output

Tags: pwm, filter, opto-isolator, low-pass

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLJlMc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to get a Raspberry Pi to give a clean, reasonably linear, 0-10V PWM signal to a device which takes in a PWM signal to control its speed. (The resistance across the PWM and ground on this device is 20k ohms).

The thing I'm trying to control is a vent-axia Sentinel MVHR. It gives you 24V as a power source, a sensing connection (Proportional control between 0-10V) and a ground.

By using a LM7810 (Google '24v-or-12v-to-10v-converter-lm7810' for the site I used...), I have successfully got a 10V supply.

Using (Google 'low pass filter calculator', first result), I got to a 100k Ohm resistor and a 680uF capacitor.,

However, I cannot for the life of me work out why I don't now get a clean, 0-10V signal after the 100k resistor. (I get a voltage range of 0.1 to 1.8V...)

If I connect the system to pin 6 (I.e. before the resistor) I get to 10V at about 50% PWM, not very useful!

Any help on what I'm missing would be great.

Comment: There is a schematic tool in the box that you use to start\edit questions.

Comment: That can source some current but it can't sink any. And the RC is not even arranged right.

Comment: What is your load/ouput on the RC?

Comment: Added a schematic - thanks for the tip! Doesn't appear to be a opto-isolator in that list so i've used a block...

I assume by RC you mean the resistor/cap combo? Absolutely no idea I'm afraid. Can't be much if all the unit is doing is sensing the voltage!!!

Answer (score -1):

For reference, here is your schematic this discussion is about:

[image]

There are a number of issues here:

You don't show the pin functions for two of the chips.  You can't expect people to look up what pins 4 and 5 of a 4N35 do, for example.  The pin numbers aren't important here and the functions are, yet you show the opposite.

The 4N35 opto-isolator has open collector output, and there is no pullup apparent.

There is no apparent source of input voltage to the 7810 regulator.

What the heck are you doing feeding 20 V (? hard to read) onto the output of a 10 V regulator?  The 78xx series can be damaged by reverse voltage.  This is a bad idea.

All in all this is a mess and its hard to tell what you actually intended.  Clean up the schematic, provide the proper documentation, and maybe it will make more sense.

Comment: 1. Sorry - added descriptions now, is that better?
2. This is probably the knowledge I'm missing. 
3. Added some text to the main description regarding the device.
4. Pin 1 is an input??

Comment: @Lik: Oh, you are showing the regulator input to output right to left!  That explains a lot, but was not clear at all from your first schematic.  When you do something unconventional, you should first have a good reason, and you need to be extra careful about documenting it.